# "+" and "-" keys seems to toggle SWT Buttons, is it possible to override this behavior?

Tags: java, swt

I am working on a Eclipse Plugin Project that uses SWT.

It seems like "+" and "-" toggles the selected SWT button.

Is there a way to override this behavior, I have tried setting the `Event.doit` field to false, but this does not work.

```
button.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
    @Override
        public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
            e.doit = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which _"Add/ Subtract Buttons"_? Do you mean the "+" and "-" keys on the keyboard?

Comment: Hi Baz, thanks for pointing it out. Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Can you add a minimal code example that shows your problem? I'm not able to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys for checkboxes and radio buttons with the following code (tested on Windows 7) :

```
// disable '+' and '-' keys
button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.character == '-' || e.character == '+') { 
            e.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

NB: User can also use <kbd>space</kbd> to toggle a checkbox, that is not disabled in my example.